# Battlefield 4 XP boosts

Tags: battlefield-4

I accidentally used the wrong xp boost and was wondering if there is any way to pause it so I don't waste it. It is a 200% xp boost and I wanted to save it in case EA doubled xp again.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to "pause" the usage of an applied XP boost is not to play. The timer on the boost only ticks down if you are actually playing.

Playing in commander mode also doesn't use up time of your boost. This could be patched out, though, so watch out.

Comment: The commander bug is already fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can`t cancel boost. If you try to replace it with other boost, you will loose current.

Boost is using up while you spawned. You can try to wait at spawn screen for squadmates to spawn on, instead running around on foot.